# Walking a directory to process two file types in Python

Tags: python, directory, os.walk

After checking for and processing a particular file type (say TypeA) in a directory, if the processed TypeA file outputs a txt file (TypeB) how do I then concentrate and process the TypeB txt file before moving back to the next original file TypeA for processing?

To clarify I have a directory of logs like...

```
file1.TypeA
file2.TypeA
file3.TypeA
```

When a run a file1.TypeA file through a function it generates txt files in the same directory, I am looking to process the txt files and grab whatever data I need and then go back to the next original file type file2.TypeA at the start of the loop and repeat the process.

I have code for walking the directory, but it seems unnecessary and a bit messy to then do another directory walk looking for txt files after the first TypeA file is processed, see below.

```
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:  
        if filename.endswith('.TypeA'): 
            run_processor_to_txt()

            for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path):
                for filename in files:  
                    if filename.endswith('.txt'): 
                        do stuff here...
```

Is there a tidier way of alternating the processing of file types once new files are generated through a function?

Comment: Can you make your script to write the output after processing file of `.typeA` to another directory, instead of the same directory ?

Comment: Hi, I can direct the generated files to a different directory, I guess i'll have to do this solution if there is no other way?  I was looking to keep all files in one place to keep things tidy.

Comment: Well you keep all files in same directory then they won't look cleaner and debugging would become troublesome, With each testing you would be generating a lot of data in the same directory and which would need to be cleaned periodically. I would suggest you to create separate directories to store new files.

Comment: Are the names of the txt files predictable? Something like `file1.typeA` generates a `file1.txt` file?

Comment: Hi Woj, they are predictable, they append the file name to the start of the new text file, something like file1_typeApredictablename.txt

Comment: Do you want to accumulate and somehow process data from all TypeB files after creation of just one, or do you need only created file? If second and filenames are predictable, you can just process needed file. If first, then `filter(lambda f: f.endswith(".txt"), os.listdir(path))` will help. (Actually you can use same for top loop too).